# zelda skyward sword falling maneuver

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

Need directions on how to use the wii remote to maneuver link while falling towards a target. I keep falling short of my target.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on what _exactly_ you want to know? It's better to be a bit too verbose than having those who want to help you with your question guess everything

Answer (score 2):

hold the wii remote flat, buttons up, facing the TV. Tilt it left to move him left, right to go right, dip it down to move forward, and tilt it up to move backwards. Also, I do believe if you hold down A you will slow down. And holding B will bring up the sailcloth.

Hopefully these tips help!